# Data range expression for list of uris (in Protégé)

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege, description-logic

I want to define a data range expression for a data property range that would define that the range is a list of uris, or a string containing a list of uris. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks! The simplest solution for me was to use data property with range xsd:anyURI and make multiple property assertions.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a few options here, and which is most appropriate will probably depend on other considerations about your domain.

### Use multiple property assertions

This is probably the simplest option, if it works for you.
If the order of the URIs isn't important, you could simply define a data property that has the range xsd:anyURI and make multiple property assertions.

### A URIList class

If the order is important, then you'll want a bit more structure.
You could define a URI-list class, whose nodes have URIs as the value of some datatype property, but then your top level property would have to be an object property (relating a thing to an URI list).

### Using regular expressions

I think that this is the least attractive solution, but if you can find a regular expression matching a URI, then you could also define a datatype property whose range is xsd:strings matching the pattern ( )* (or something similar).